# React create custom event

Tags: reactjs, events

Basically all i want to be able to do is create a custom event that i can monitor in the console. For example when a user clicks search button i want to create a custom event called "start-search".

In my jsx i have following:

```
const searchClick = () => {
  let event = new Event("start-search");
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
};

<button id="test" onClick={searchClick}>
```

For some context the idea here is that i could create a custom event called "start-search" and "end-search" that someone else could write js/jquery to do custom stuff during a given event.

I would like to be able to use similar to following in dev tools console and see event fired as expected:

[image: monitorEvents("start-search")]

Comment: Here's the page with what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @Hugo Zapata So I already tried the steps on that page (see updated code). How can i monitor this in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom event with `const event = new Event('start-search');`

then you can dispatch it at the appropriate time with `window.dispatchEvent(event)`

And to monitor from the console you would write (assuming you want to monitor on the window object):

```
monitorEvents(window, "start-search")
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: So see updated post. Monitor events shows undefined.

Comment: It shows undefined because the function monitorEvents doesn't return anything. If you  trigger an event it should display the log item.